# Errors while installing apache bloodbound

Tags: python, postgresql, fedora, apache-bloodhound

after this command line :

```
python bloodhound_setup.py --environments_directory=/opt/bloodhound/environments bloodbound=DEF
```

I get this

```
Error: TimeoutError: Unable to get database connection within 0 seconds. (OperationalError: could not connect to server: Connection refused
        Is the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting
        TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
could not connect to server: Connection refused
        Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
        TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
)
```

Any help ?
thanks

Comment: is PostgreSQL installed and running?

Comment: It looks like you are following the [Bloodhound installation wiki](https://issues.apache.org/bloodhound/wiki/BloodhoundInstall#Installation). The last option should be `--default-product-prefix=DEF`, not `bloodbound=DEF`. As to what's causing the error, I would look first at the suggestion by Wimmel.

Comment: Yes PostgresSQL is installed and running, Since i added : # IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/32               md5
to my pg_hba.conf file the error has disappeared.trying to run it on port 8778, i got this : Error starting Trac server on 0.0.0.0:8778 view at http://127.0.0.1:8778/
[Errno 98] Address already in use